# Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses

Tags: assembly, macos, x86-64

I have a sample piece of code that writes the value of the xmm6 register into a memory location. The code is in NASM:

```
value:
    dd 0

movq [value], xmm6
```

However I am getting the error when I tried to compile it to macho64 format:

> 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses.

Is there a way to resolve this? I am new to x86_64 assembly so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the question so only the code is in the silly code-scrolling-thing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to tell assembler that you wont to point to 8-byte memory location:

```
movq qword[value], xmm6
```

Comment: Is this because xmm6 has a size of qword so I must put qword to balance it?

Comment: No, you wont to operate with 64-bit variable named value. The xmm registers are 128-bit size if you wont to copy 128-bits to memory then use "movdqa  dqword [value]".

Comment: I've declared value as dd (32-bit) though, so I should use word then.

Comment: No, word is 16 bit dword is 32 bit.

Comment: But with movq instructions you can move only qword.

Comment: You don't need a size override; `movq`  already implies a `qword` load/store.  This doesn't do anything about using a `[disp32]` addressing mode (impossible for Mach-O) instead of a `[RIP + rel32]` addressing mode.  Also, the OP used `dd` so the right suggestion is `movss` or `movd`, not `movq` at all.  Or to change the data section.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have solved by own question:

```
value:
    dd 0

default rel
movq [value], xmm6
```

Is this valid?

Comment: Yes and no! Because now you have the default pointed size 8-byte what is not very smart in 32 bit (4-byte) assembler.

Comment: Yes, `default rel` will get it to link, but then you're storing 8 bytes (`movq`), going outside the 4 bytes you reserved with `dd`.